# Passport-facebook FacebookTokenError: This authorization code has been used

Tags: node.js, facebook, passport.js, passport-facebook

This is my passport.js

```
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;


var User = require('./app/models/users');
var config = require('./config');

module.exports = function (passport) {


    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });



    passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
            clientID: config.facebook.appId,
            clientSecret: config.facebook.appSecret,
            callbackURL: config.facebook.redirectUrl,
            profileFields: ['id', 'name', 'displayName', 'emails', 'photos']

        },
        function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            process.nextTick(function () {

                User.findOne({'facebook.id': profile.id}, function (err, user) {

                        console.log(profile);

                    if (err) {
                        // console.log("tick errr");
                        return done(err)
                    }
                    ;
                    if (user)
                        return done(null, user);
                    else {
                        var newUser = new User();
                        newUser.facebook.id = profile.id;
                        newUser.facebook.token = accessToken;
                        newUser.facebook.name = profile.displayName;
                        newUser.facebook.email = profile.emails[0].value;
                        newUser.facebook.picurl = profile.photos[0].value;
                        // console.log("access to ken is "+accessToken);
                        //console.log(newUser.facebook.id);

                        newUser.save(function (err) {
                            if (err)
                                console.log(err);
                            return done(null, newUser);
                        })
                    }
                });
                });
            // done(null, profile);
        }
    ));
```

api.js

```
 api.get('/auth/facebook', function (req, res, next) {

        passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope: ['email']})(req, res, next);
    });


    api.get('/auth/facebook/callback',

        passport.authenticate('facebook', {


            successRedirect: '#/home',
            failureRedirect: '#/login'


        })

    );


    };
```

I am having trouble using facebook login.
I am getting following error:

```
FacebookTokenError: This authorization code has been used.
   at Strategy.parseErrorResponse (c:\Users\chetan kanjani\WebstormProjects\letsgo\node_modules\passport-facebook\lib\strategy.js:199:12)
   at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (c:\Users\chetan kanjani\WebstormProjects\letsgo\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:345:16)
   at c:\Users\chetan kanjani\WebstormProjects\letsgo\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:171:43
   at c:\Users\chetan kanjani\WebstormProjects\letsgo\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:177:18
   at passBackControl (c:\Users\chetan kanjani\WebstormProjects\letsgo\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:123:9)
   at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (c:\Users\chetan kanjani\WebstormProjects\letsgo\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:143:7)
   at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
   at _stream_readable.js:908:16
   at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
```

I am able to login on facebook page and then after that this error shows up.
The details which i am fetching from facebook are still successfully stored in my database;
I think it has something to do with the auth/facebook/callback

users.js file :

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local: {

        name: String,
        username: {type: String, index: {unique: true}},
        password: {type: String, select: false}
    },
    facebook: {
        id: String,
        token: String,
        email: String,
        name: String,
        picurl: String,
    },
    favouriteid: [{eventid: String}]

});


UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {

    var user = this;


    if (!user.isModified('local.password')) return next();

    bcrypt.hash(user.local.password, null, null, function (err, hash) {
        if(err) return next(err);

        user.local.password = hash;
        next();

    });
});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(password) {

    var user = this;

    var a = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.local.password);

    if (a == true)
        return true;
    else {
        console.log('error in compare password');
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: do you found the solution? Because I have the same issue...

Comment: @aral-roca only solution I found is to sign-in through client side and then send the token and the login data from client side. I used ngFacebook on client side. If anyone gets a solution on server side. Please share

Comment: I have answered this question in there:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35875612/facebooktokenerror-this-authorization-code-has-been-used/35970805#35970805

Comment: @endrcn your answer isn't a solution, we know what causes it, we're here for solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Error occur when leaved Apps login data in your Facebook account.
Delete your login data to solve this error.

1. Log in Facebook
2. Go to settings
3. Go to Apps
4. Search login data of your app.
5. Push the "X"button

After follow above progress, try to login Facebook Login.